# Proving $x^2 = 12y+7$ unsolvable via parity contradiction

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am recently enrolled in a Set Theory course as part of my degree. I am familiar with the symbolic representation of logic and sets, translating and defining them, but my professor doesn't approach it like that, at least not yet.

At the moment he is failing to attempt to introduce us to direct and indirect proofs. I just don't get it.

I can wrap my head around the logical convolutions required to setup an argument but writing the argument is where I fail.

For example, in front of me, I have the statement: 
There are no integers x and y, such that $$x^2=12y+7$$

I am told to prove by contradiction which turns the arg into:
There are integers x and y, such that $$x^2=12y+7$$

The rest of the setup goes: Assume that there are integers x and y, such that $$x^2=12y+7$$ Obtain a contradiction

This is where my process begins to breakdown, because I know there are points where the contradiction is true, and in all bias the given is false, however the professor's answer proves the given to be true on the basis of odds and evens which doesn't make sense to me.

Can anyone help?

Comment: "I know there are points where the contradiction is true, and in all bias the given is false, however the professor's answer proves the given to be true on the basis of odds and evens which doesn't make sense to me." Can you clarify what you mean by this?

Comment: You need to assume that there ARE integers that exist that solve the equation, and then, by using odd and even integers, show that these can not happen.  Since you are using true algebraic arguments, all those true steps that you take must all be correct but it's the assumption then that must be off.

Comment: This has nothing to do with set theory - it's really just about logical reasoning / proofs. I can't tell from what you've written whether you don't understand proof by contradiction (as a general proof strategy), or whether you don't understand the particular argument "on the basis of odd and evens", or both!

Comment: "This is where my process begins to breakdown, because I know there are points where the contradiction is true, "  There are non-integers $x,y$ where $x^2=12y+7$ but there aren't any integers where $x^2=12y+7$.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that there is an integer solution to $x^2=12y+7$. 
Consider the equation over the ring $\Bbb Z/4$. Then it becomes $x^2=3$ and $x$ and $y$ is still a solution modulo $4$. However, the equation has obviously no solution in $\Bbb Z/4$, since every square is congruent $0$ or $1$ modulo $4$. This is the desired contradiction.

Comment: Given that the OP seems to be having difficulty with the argument in parity form, it  seems highly unlikely that they are familiar with *quotient rings*.

Comment: Fortunately one can say modulo $4$ instead, which the OP is familiar with, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what is essentially Dietrich Burde's proof stated in less formal terms:

Assume there are integers $x,y$ such that $x^2=12y+7$. $x$ must either be odd or even, e.g. either $x=2k-1$ or $x=2k$. Therefore, either $x^2=4k^2-4k+1$ or $x^2=4k^2$. Now look at cases.

Case 1: $x$ is odd and $x^2=12y+7 \Rightarrow 4k^2-4k+1=12y+7$. Rearranging, we get $4(k^2-k-3y)=6$. But $4\not \mid 6$, so the assumption $x$ is odd is wrong.

Case 2: $x$ is even and $x^2=12y+7 \Rightarrow 4k^2=12y+7$. Rearranging, we get $4(k^2-3y)=7$. But $4\not \mid 7$, so the assumption $x$ is even is wrong.

If $x$ is neither odd nor even, there is no such $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $x$ is an even integer.  Then $x^2$ is an even integer.  (Because $x = 2m$ for some integer $m$ and $x^2 =(2m)^2 =4m^2 =2\times (2m^2)$ and $2m^2$ is an integer.)

But if $y$ is an integer then $12y + 7$ is odd.  (Because $12y+7 = 2(6y+3) + 1$ and $6y+3$ is an integer and integers in the form $2k +1$ are odd. [Because $2$ can't divide $2k+1$.  $\frac {2k+1}2= k +\frac 12$ is not an integer.])

So we can't have $x^2 = 12y+7$ where $x^2 $ is even and $12y+7$ is not.

So there can't be a solution where $x$ is  an even integer and $y$ is an integer.

Suppose $x$ is an odd integer.  The $x = 2m + 1$ for some integer $m$.  So $x^2= (2m+1)^2 = 4m^2 + 4m + 1$.

So if $x^2 = 12y + 7$ then

$4m^2 + 4m + 1 = 12y + 7$ and

$4m^2 + 4m = 12y + 6$ and

$4(m^2 + m) = 12y + 6$ and

$m^2 + m = \frac {12y + 6}4 = 3y+ 1\frac 12$.

If $y$ is an integer then $3y + 1\frac 12$ is not an integer.  But $m^2 + m$ is an integer

So there cannot be any solutions where $x$ is an odd number and $y$ is an integer.

So if $y$ is an integer and $x^2=12y+7$ then $x$ can not be an even nor an odd integer.  SO $x$ can not be an integer.

So there are no solutions to $x^2=12y + 7$ where $x$ and $y$ are both integers.

....

In general this is hinting at at a well known result that you are probably unfamiliar with yet.

If $x$ is even,  Then $x^2$ is a multiple of $4$. (If $x = 2m$ then $x^2 = 4m^2$.

If $x$ is odd, Then $x^2$ has remainder $1$ when divided by $4$. (If $x = 2m +1$ then $x^2 = 4m^2 + 4m +1 = 4(m^2 + m) + 1$.)

If $x$ is an integer, then it is impossible for $x^2$ to have remainder $2$ or $3$ when divided by $4$.

So $12y + 7$ has remainder $3$ when divided by $4$ and that is impossible.